# How do I create a class variable that can affect the object passed through the constructor?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, pass-by-reference

So I have class `A`, which has an object of class `B` as a class variable.
I constructed an object of class `B` in the main (`objB`) , and use class `A`'s constructor to pass `objB` into class A (and assigned it to class variable called `objC` of type `B`).

How can I make it so whenever I call `objC.do()` it can change the original `objB` as well?

Comment: You should include a **[mcve]**, but it sounds like you 're looking for a reference, so that your `A` constructor would look like `A(B& objB)`

Comment: @Tas: While OP did not provide code, I think his example is minimal and complete, and doesn't really need verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a `B` member, use a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) as a member:

```
class A {
    B& the_b;
    // etc.
public:
    A(B& some_b) : the_B { some_B } { }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. For some reason I couldn't find this simple solution online

Comment: Although this brings up questions about what assignment of two `A` objects should do, e.g. `A a1(b1); A a2(b2); a1 = a2;`. The default given this code will be "it has the same effect as `b1 = b2;`". For the answer "you can't do that", add a deleted `operator=`. For the answer "now `a1` refers to `b2`", you'll need to change the member from a reference to a pointer.